# android button needs 2 click to make effect

Tags: android, button

I have encounter strange behavior of the button. Button has two action.

- First action is to set text inside button and
- second to Change integer value.

  When I click once, only integer value is changed. Text is changed only after second click on it.
  Help me please to fix it :)

button layout

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/delres"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
android:layout_below="@id/soffice"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/face"
android:onClick="delrestor_Click"
android:text="Button"
/>
```

code for button

```
public void delrestor_Click(View v){
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);  
        if(p.get_active()==1){
            p.set_active(0);
            p.set_ranking(0);
            dres.setText("Delete");
            db.updateCandidate(p);
        }
        else{
            p.set_active(1);
            p.set_ranking(0);
            dres.setText("Restore");
            db.updateCandidate(p);
        }
        db.close();
    }
```

button initialization

```
dres = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delres);
if(p.get_active()==1){
            dres.setText("Delete");
        }
        else dres.setText("Restore");
```

Comment: Dont undestand how. I exctly know that p.set is done as i am getting imidiat notification from other activity. Only p.setText does not respond from first time

Comment: put log and debug your code, you will come know exactly what happening with your code.

Comment: there is log in updatecandidate, so i know that values vas seted properly

Comment: Its not changing button text on first click?

Comment: No, first time text is change only after second click, after this it works normaly and tooks only one click to change text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:dublicateParentState to pass focus to button